# For an asymmetric bilinear pairing, can I get $g_2^t$ from $g_1^t$?

Tags: bilinear-pairing

Let $e:G_1\times G_2\to G_t$ be an asymmetric bilinear pairing, $g_1$ be a generator of $G_1$ and $g_2$ be a generator of $G_2$. Can we compute $g_2^t$ from $g_1^t$ when $t$ is unknown?

Answer (score 2):

We classify the bilinear groups in three types.

- In type 1, there is an efficient algorithm given $g_1^t$ output $g_2^t$, and an efficient algorithm given $g_2^t$ output $g_1^t$. This case is also called the symmetric case, because with any loss of generality, it's a bit like $\mathbb{G}_1= \mathbb{G}_2$ (and in the type 1 I know, the groups are indeed the same).
- In type 2, There is only one way allowed (from $g_1^t$ to $g_2^t$).
- In type 3, there is no such known functions.

It's noticeable that type $1$ has more structure than type $3$, and then for security reason, the bit size of group elements increases (because the adversary has more power).

It's also noticeable that for type $1$, DDH is easy in $\mathbb{G}_1$, and in $\mathbb{G}_2$, and in type $2$, DDH is easy in $\mathbb{G}_1$.

So the answer is yes if your group is type $\leq 2$, and else no.

Comment: This doesn't sound right; consider the type 1 case where we have a generator $g_1$ and a generator $g_2 = g_1^x$.  Then, the claim above is that given $g_1^y$, we can get $g_2^y = g_1^{xy}$; that solves the CDH problem.  I had thought that CDH was hard, even in type 1 pairings.

Comment: In type 1, as far as I know $g_2=g_1.$

Comment: With type 1, it is common that $\mathbb{G}_1 = \mathbb{G}_2$; does that necessarily mean that they share the same generator?

Comment: Okay, but concretly how your application from $g^\alpha_1$ to $g^\alpha_2$ will work? If it is juste the exponentiation of $x$, it implies $x$ is publicly known.

Comment: You're the one who wrote "In type 1, there is an efficient algorithm given $g_1^t$ output $g_2^t$"; that's the part that I said "doesn't sound right".  If you're asking for a concrete algorithm for doing that transform, well, you said such an algorithm existed, not me.

Comment: Okay, so $(\mathbb{G}, g_1),(\mathbb{G}, g_2)$ is not of type $1,$ if $x$ is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. We would need additional structure or information.

However, we can solve the decisional problem of determining whether any given element $h\in G_2$ is equal to $g_2^t$. To do this we compute $e(g_1^t,g_2)$ and $e(g_1,h)$. If the two pairings are equal then $h=g_2^t$.